# Removing the boundary from a manifold with boundary

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

Let $M$ be a manifold with boundary $\partial M$. Can we say that $M'=M-\partial M$ is a closed manifold. I think it is correct, for example take $D$ to be the disk this a manifold with boundary the circle $S^1$. Then $D-S^1$ is a closed manifold. The definition of a closed manifold being that compact + without boundary. removing the boundary from a manifold with boundary certainly give a manifold without boundary so the problem is to determine wether $M-\partial M$ is compact or not. And another question is that wether every manifold with boundary is compact or not. Thank you for your help!

Comment: As you can see in your example, the resulting manifold will not be compact ($D \setminus S^1$ is not compact !)

Comment: The closed upper half-plane in $\Bbb{R}^2$ is a manifold with boundary but is not compact.

Comment: From these two comments i see that a manifold with boundary can and can not be compact. But removing the boundary is always non compact is this correct ?

Comment: @palio It will always be non-compact granted that it either _did have a boundary_ or was non-compact already. For instance, $S^2 - \partial S^2$ is still compact.

Comment: isn't $\partial S^2=\emptyset$?, I'm talking about manifolds WITH boundary from which we remove this boundary, is removing the boundary makes it non compact whether it was compact or not with the boundary ?

Comment: If $\partial S$ is non-empty, then $S\setminus\partial S$ is not compact because we can choose a sequence tending towards a point in the boundary (if the boundary were still there) which has no convergent subsequence. Alternatively, a compact subspace of a hausdorff space is closed which $S\setminus\partial S$ clearly is not.